# Delete duplicate rows with

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows

I need to make a combination of fields a & b UNIQUE. There are some duplicate rows now. What I intend to do is to leave the row with **lowest non-zero value** of another field c.

1) find duplicates
2) delete all rows but the one that has the **lowest non-zero value** of field c.

Performance is also important, because the table has quite some records already...

I can't figure it out on my own and I'm pretty confused already :/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary table where you can store the distinct records and then truncate the original table and insert data from temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (a INT,b INT,c INT) 

INSERT INTO temp_table (a,b,c) SELECT * FROM table1 where c in (select min(c) from table1 group by a,b);

TRUNCATE table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c) SELECT * FROM temp_table ;
```

Try this. May be it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a81e6/14/0

Have a look at the fiddle, you would just change the SELECT to DELETE and it would delete the two records it selected (i.e. the two duplicates with the higher C column).

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the names and columns of the tables it would be easy to provide the correct solution but anyway you can use the command as following

```
delete from highscores where id = (select * from (select id from highscores order by score desc limit 10,1) as t)
```

Hope this delete all the rows except the lowest value but can't do that which have non-zero values or less than zero values. It will keep the lowest value and delete all others. You can't have the oranges and apples in the single command, You have to run two commands. First for deletion of less than 0 values and then have the lowest record.